# Memory leak in go http server and fasthttp

Tags: debugging, go, memory-leaks, server, fasthttp

My code was a simple fasthttp server like its github examples
but that had an unknown memory leak.
Then I tried to find it and cleared my codes and it had that problem again.

Then I ran just the official example and even that had memory leak (meaning that I watch the memory usage on windows process manager and its used memory grows up in loads and go does not release even after a while until my windows crashed).

Then I used the std net/http by a very simple hello world server and I had that problem again. My memory usage grows by every request and Go does not release it.

My version is  go 1.11.2 windows/amd64

and this is my code that have this problem:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func sayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    message := r.URL.Path
    message = strings.TrimPrefix(message, "/")
    message = "Hello " + message
    w.Write([]byte(message))
    r.Body.Close()
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayHello)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe the workload.  Are you using a testing tool, hitting from a web browser or something else?  To be clear, are you saying that running this program crashed Windows?

Comment: no i just use the insomnia for testing and opera browser but i request several times. and yes when i try to serve a big file for downloading my windows hangs cause of full memory

Comment: The code in the question does not serve big files.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: i can't put my code but the leaking reason of this code is the answer of why my code is leaking too and so my code is like the http serveContent

Comment: The code in the question does not leak. Please update the question with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You say that when using the Hello-world example "Go does release it."  Do you mean "Go does not release it"?

Comment: yes I edited that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was not cause of library and not a bug.
it’s cause of GC behavior. its not a memory leak.
study more about how Go’s GC works to understand and don’t worry at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Go http.Request documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)

```
// The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
// Handler does not need to.
```

So you should remove the `r.Body.Close()` call, as it is not needed.

Comment: so why its memory is growing up? can it be a bug in Go 1.11 ?